# Error linking test-suite to library

Tags: haskell, build, static-libraries, cabal, quickcheck

I'm trying to write a test using quickcheck for a simple lexer i've written.
However, I seem to be falling foul of some sort of link error

I've building using cabal-dev

my .cabal file is building a library "mylib" 
The library section has under its exposed modules section Lexical.Token and under the test-suite I have "mylib" listed under build_depends, and I also have Lexical.token listed under other modules.

What am I missing? The error I get out of ghc (7.4.1) is as follows:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Token'
            with actual type `mylib-0.0.0.1:Lexical.Token.Token'
Expected type: [Token]
Actual type: [mylib-0.0.0.1:Lexical.Token.Token]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cabal is conflicted over two locations for the "Lexical.Token" module. Confusingly, they're both the same file.

1. It's resolving `mylib-0.0.0.1` from your `build-depends` to the "locally installed and registered" version of `mylib`.
2. It's resolving `Lexical.Token` in the source as an `other-modules` entry, something that should be *exposed* through your test suite.

Fix it be removing `Lexical.Token` from `other-modules`, I imagine. Your test suite should not share code with your tested code, but instead import all the modules as if your tested code were an external library.